# WordPress backend is loading without style

Tags: css

My website WordPress backend is not loading with CSS….the frontend is working fine but once i try login to my wordpress admin the page load without any style .. I have reinstalled WordPress core file many time and i have try and added these (define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true ); in wp-config.php but problem still not fixed

[image]

the error in chrome consul is showing :

Refused to apply style from 'https://www.csm.school/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load%5Bchunk_0%5D=dashicons,admin-bar,wp-pointer,site-health,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-m&load%5Bchunk_1%5D=enus,widgets,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=5.4.2' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Function.php :

```
<?php

// simple error trapping on screen
// Report simple running errors
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE);

// full errors
//  error_reporting(E_ALL);


/**
 * Customify functions and definitions
 *
 * @link    https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/
 *
 * @package customify
 */

/**
 *  Same the hook `the_content`
 *
 * @TODO: do not effect content by plugins
 *
 * 8 WP_Embed:run_shortcode
 * 8 WP_Embed:autoembed
 * 10 wptexturize
 * 10 wpautop
 * 10 shortcode_unautop
 * 10 prepend_attachment
 * 10 wp_make_content_images_responsive
 * 11 capital_P_dangit
 * 11 do_shortcode
 * 20 convert_smilies
 */
global $wp_embed;
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', array( $wp_embed, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'capital_P_dangit' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_content', 'convert_smilies' );


/**
 *  Same the hook `the_content` but not auto P
 *
 * @TODO: do not effect content by plugins
 *
 * 8 WP_Embed:run_shortcode
 * 8 WP_Embed:autoembed
 * 10 wptexturize
 * 10 shortcode_unautop
 * 10 prepend_attachment
 * 10 wp_make_content_images_responsive
 * 11 capital_P_dangit
 * 11 do_shortcode
 * 20 convert_smilies
 */
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', array( $wp_embed, 'run_shortcode' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', array( $wp_embed, 'autoembed' ), 8 );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'wptexturize' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'shortcode_unautop' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'wp_make_content_images_responsive' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'capital_P_dangit' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'do_shortcode' );
add_filter( 'customify_the_title', 'convert_smilies' );

// Include the main Customify class.
require_once get_template_directory() . '/inc/class-customify.php';

/**
 * Main instance of Customify.
 *
 * Returns the main instance of Customify.
 *
 * @return Customify
 */
function Customify() {
    // phpc:ignore WordPress.NamingConventions.ValidFunctionName.
    return Customify::get_instance();
}

Customify();
```

Load-style.php:

```
    <?php

/**
 * Disable error reporting
 *
 * Set this to error_reporting( -1 ) for debugging
 */
error_reporting( 0 );

/** Set ABSPATH for execution */
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    define( 'ABSPATH', dirname( __DIR__ ) . '/' );
}

define( 'WPINC', 'wp-includes' );

require ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/noop.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/script-loader.php';
require ABSPATH . WPINC . '/version.php';

$protocol = $_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL'];
if ( ! in_array( $protocol, array( 'HTTP/1.1', 'HTTP/2', 'HTTP/2.0' ) ) ) {
    $protocol = 'HTTP/1.0';
}

$load = $_GET['load'];
if ( is_array( $load ) ) {
    ksort( $load );
    $load = implode( '', $load );
}

$load = preg_replace( '/[^a-z0-9,_-]+/i', '', $load );
$load = array_unique( explode( ',', $load ) );

if ( empty( $load ) ) {
    header( "$protocol 400 Bad Request" );
    exit;
}

$rtl            = ( isset( $_GET['dir'] ) && 'rtl' == $_GET['dir'] );
$expires_offset = 31536000; // 1 year.
$out            = '';

$wp_styles = new WP_Styles();
wp_default_styles( $wp_styles );

if ( isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) && stripslashes( $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'] ) === $wp_version ) {
    header( "$protocol 304 Not Modified" );
    exit();
}

foreach ( $load as $handle ) {
    if ( ! array_key_exists( $handle, $wp_styles->registered ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $style = $wp_styles->registered[ $handle ];

    if ( empty( $style->src ) ) {
        continue;
    }

    $path = ABSPATH . $style->src;

    if ( $rtl && ! empty( $style->extra['rtl'] ) ) {
        // All default styles have fully independent RTL files.
        $path = str_replace( '.min.css', '-rtl.min.css', $path );
    }

    $content = get_file( $path ) . "\n";

    if ( strpos( $style->src, '/' . WPINC . '/css/' ) === 0 ) {
        $content = str_replace( '../images/', '../' . WPINC . '/images/', $content );
        $content = str_replace( '../js/tinymce/', '../' . WPINC . '/js/tinymce/', $content );
        $content = str_replace( '../fonts/', '../' . WPINC . '/fonts/', $content );
        $out    .= $content;
    } else {
        $out .= str_replace( '../images/', 'images/', $content );
    }
}

header( "Etag: $wp_version" );
header( 'Expires: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + $expires_offset ) . ' GMT' );
header( "Cache-Control: public, max-age=$expires_offset" );

echo $out;
exit;
```

> .Htaccess:

```
<FilesMatch index.php>
Order Allow,Deny
Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Hi @Arnab88 could you please add the code to the question with which you're loading all of your stylesheets? Most likely it's in the functions.php file. Second, can you please check if your CSS file has a specific header or so?

Comment: sure i will dd all the content of function.php and load-style.php in the question if that is what you mean

Comment: Where do you load the `load-style.php` file? It seems to me that it's never included and so it doesn't do anything in the first place. Or am I wrong in this?

Comment: but WordPress backend css is loaded from it so i thought if the load-style.php is configured correctly the admin page will display css

Comment: Don't touch core files (`load-style.php` in this case) under any circumstances. Yours has been edited already and a header is missing in the line #83.

Comment: @Arnab88 I deleted the answer so so that it doesn't look like the question is already answered. Aside from that, I don't know any other solution.

Comment: Max is right: load-styles should have a line `header( 'Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8' );` amongst the other `header()` lines at the bottom. Why did you delete that? Can you put it back?

Comment: I haven't deleted or edited anything inside load-style.php.. but I recently did a website clean to delete some malware .. still the same thing :( even after adding the header mentioned by @rup

Answer (score 1):

The load-style.php URL you provided above is redirecting to the login form and this is why the inspector is complaining about a HTML response.

I tested this on a fresh installation and WordPress returns the styles even if you are logged off so you much have some .htaccess or PHP code redirecting the load-style.php file to the login form.

You have also removed a line of the core which tells the browser the PHP script is a CSS file, though I suspect Chrome would still parse it so long as the response was actually CSS, you should never do this and as such I would also recommend re-installing WordPress via Dashboard => Updates to get the core back to its correct state.

Comment: load-style.php might be missing some the lines but i think the is not what is causing the problem (because i added all the missing lines but still not showing style) .. as you mentioned it would be something else i cant find it :( .  ( I have added the .htaccess file in the main question )

Comment: It is load-styles.php redirecting to the login form HTML that is the reason your CMS is unstyled. It looks like it may be your wp-admin folder .htaccess as the following redirecting is the reason the login form is unstyled: https://csm.school/wp-admin/css/login.css - you can see it too redirects to the login form instead of serving the CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Probably some (cache) plugin does this in your admin

Add this in config.

`define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );`